# Find control characters in MySQL

Tags: mysql, string, control-characters

What is the best way to find control characters within a string in MySQL? I have a table and want to get all records, that contain control characters. Something like

```
SELECT * FROM Customer WHERE Name = *ControlCharFilter*;
```

in C# it would be

```
Customer.Where(x => x.Name.Any(y => char.IsControl(y));
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

MySQL supports regular expressions with POSIX character classes:

```
SELECT * FROM Customer WHERE Name RLIKE '[[:cntrl:]]+'
```

There's more information [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/regexp.html).

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT * FROM Customer WHERE Name = "%ControlCharFilter%";
```

or are you looking for something more complex?

Comment: Sorry, I beleive you have tottaly misunderstood what OP wants